# Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql306.juichost.ml' (113 "No route to host")

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I have looked everywhere for a fix, but could only find ones for localhost or private sites.

I keep getting this error:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql306.juichost.ml' (113 "No route to host")

The website is [Here](http://ppyazi.com/license). I am using [this](http://juichost.ml) website host for mysql, but hostmonster for the actual hosting.

I have tried `ping sql306.juichost.ml` and gotten this:

> ping: sendto: Host is down
>   Request timeout for icmp_seq 876.

I have no idea what to that means though.

In the error log I see:

> [01-Nov-2017 09:52:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'inc/database.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/aussieug/public_html/ppyazi/license/login.php on line 2

And

> [01-Nov-2017 09:52:56 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: con in /home/aussieug/public_html/ppyazi/license/login.php on line 14

Line 2:

```
include 'inc/database.php';
```

Line 14:

```
$checksettings = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `settings` LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Please keep in mind that I am very new to terminal and php so I need detailed answers.

Comment: Syntax error on line 17. /s http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Just try `ping sql306.juichost.ml` and it will be crystal clear what's going on.

Comment: Do you have access to the terminal on both servers?

Comment: Don't know what ping you are using, but you should have seen this line: `Pinging sql306.juichost.ml [192.168.0.196] with 32 bytes of data:`. As 192.168.0.196 is a **private** address, you cannot access that sql host from outside their network.

Comment: Thanks @fvu. I have done this and gotten this: 'ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 876'. What does that mean?

Comment: I want the sql public though.

Comment: I paste 'Pinging sql306.juichost.ml [192.168.0.196] with 32 bytes of data:' into terminal and it said '-bash: Pinging: command not found'

Comment: That line was not meant to be executed, it's what ping on my system says, clearly indicating that the sql host has a **private** address only. That is intentional, to keep people from using their sql hosts from the outside, so I guess there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: I only have terminal on my Mac.

Comment: What can I do to fix the site though? Change sql providers?